# Why $f''(c)>0$ implies $f''(x)>0$ for $x$ close to $c$ for a continuous function?

Tags: calculus

Here the assertion is made that for a twice continuously differentiable function, if $f''(c)>0, f''(x)>0$ for $x$ close to $c$.

I am wondering why this is the case, because in theory it seems that the second derivative could possess only a single point at which it is greater than zero, and be less than zero for all other points.
thanks
[image]

Comment: What continuous function can you think of that is greater than zero at one point and less than zero at every other point ?

Answer (score 1):

We should make use of the continuity condition. Let us denote $x = f''(c) > 0$, then pick $\varepsilon = \frac{x}{2} > 0$, then the continuity suggests that there is some $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x_0$ with $|x-x_0| < \delta$, we must have $|f''(x)-f''(x_0)|<\varepsilon$. Therefore, we have found an interval $(c-\delta, c+\delta)$ such that the value of the function $f''$ is at least $x-\varepsilon = x - \frac{x}{2} = \frac{x}{2} > 0$, so $f''$ is positive on this interval. This interval would be what ``close'' means.

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully you cited your source, which says that "we assumed that the second derivative is continuous". If $f''$ is continuous and $f''(c)>0$, then there is a neighbourhood of $c$ where $f''$ is positive. (This is because $(0,\infty]\subset\mathbb R$ is open and thus $\{x\mid f''(x)>0\} = (f'')^{-1}((0,\infty])$ is open aswell).